# Checking Facebook Status Using Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to check facebook status of another page from ruby script. First of all is it possible. I have been doing the following:

1. I got developer account
2. I got app key and secret
3. I installed json_pure gem

**Here is my code:**

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
>      require 'json/pure'
>      require 'net/http'
>
>     url ="https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed?access_token=app_id|app_secret"
>     uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))  
>     #to remove specia codes encode
>     #to remoce whitespace strip
>
>     req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.to_s)
>     res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http|
>       http.request(req)
>     }
>     html = res.body
>     res = JSON.parse(html)
> ```

**Here is the error:**

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread': An existing connection
 was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) instead of `Net::Http`

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
status = @graph.get_connections("me", user_id, "status")
```

Comment: how do i get oauth_access_token from app id and app secret

Comment: `oauth_consumer_key: App ID`
`oauth_consumer_secret: App Secret`